# Matching ? character in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my problem is simply I want to match "?" character but it seems htaccess not matching with ? character. What I want is simply

```
site.com/search.html?age=1&color=2

to

site.com/index.php?page=search&age=1&color&2
```

My htaccess

```
RewriteRule search.html?(.*)$ index.php?page=search&$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`. Besides you don't even need to match `?` here.

Replace your rule with:

```
RewriteRule ^search\.html$ index.php?page=search [L,QSA,NC]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one. That's the reason you don't need to capture existing query string here.